# Netherlands visit visa bank statement

Tags: visas, netherlands, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am on a student visa in the UK and was planning to go to the Netherlands. For the visa it states I need at least a 3 month bank balance. My question here is get my scholarship stipend of €1058 every month, then it gets spent by the end of the month.

For the requirement, is it necessary to have the money fixed for the 3 months or do I just need to show that I have the money when I apply for the visa?

Plus I have a son who is 1 year old. Is it also for him necessary to have the 34 euros per day requirement?

Comment: How long are you planning to stay in the Netherlands?

Comment: For a week during the Easter holidays

Answer (score 1):

The Dutch will want to know whether you can afford the cost of your stay. Having 3 months of statements proves that you have a regular income and there's no funds parking.

As it happens, you seem to be a bit short on the income side. Presumably you have some expenses that will continue even during your trip, so you don't have the full €1058 available (if you don't have such expenses, your visa application will be rejected straight away as it's seen as an indication you don't plan to return to the UK). You'll need to show savings.

Your child will need a place to stay, and will need food. €34 is not a lot in the Netherlands; you can't get a regular hotel room for that. So you can't expect your kid to stay for free. It's reasonable that you'll need to show you can pay for him too.

(Belgium in comparison assumes €85/day, which is a far more realistic rate.)

Comment: Hi, what if I add another 1000 pounds into the account as a savings this month apart from the monthly payment of 1058? Will that suffice I take out the statement next month in March for the period starring from December?

Comment: Don't transfer the money into your account, show that you have the savings (that would be the statement for that savings account, I guess).

Comment: Okay thanks. One more question then.. I should show 2 bank statements then? Because in the savings account there was no previous balance just hot 1000 today

Comment: @AhmedSaeed: That's the sort of unusual activity they're watching out for. How did €1000 suddenly materialize from someone whose money is normally "spent by the end of the month"? They might fear it's a short-term loan, and not real spendable income.

Comment: So what do you suggest I do, because I am actually transferring that money from my local bank account to my UK bank account. I would wait for a month and a half before applying for the visa.

Comment: @AhmedSaeed: In that case, bring statements of that account as well ! Money moved between your own accounts is not an issue.